# Need help making a legend for a plot using the Vegan Package in R

Tags: r, plot, legend, vegan, factor-analysis

I am currently trying to plot a legend on my PCO graph using the vegan package, but the pch on the legend and on the plot are not the same. Does anybody know how to solve this problem? I have attached code and replication data accordingly. Many thanks

```
library(vegan)
pco2 <- capscale(vec2 ~ 1, add = TRUE)
pco2
ordiplot(pco2, display = 'sites', type = 'n', cex=.75, main="Biotechnology Dissimilarity")
points (pco2, col = MyMeta$Group0, pch=MyMeta$Group0)
legend(x="bottomleft", legend=levels(MyMeta$Group), col=MyMeta$Group0, pch=MyMeta$Group0)
```

Below is the replication Data

```
vec2 <- structure(c(5.6e-05, 0.000264854, 0.031144847, 1.36e-05, 0.0077926, 
9.61e-06, 0.018901651, 0.005618188, 0.025462273, 0.078385688, 
0.004847819, 0.017850528, 0.000467735, 5.4e-05, 0.001046951, 
0.006335814, 0.03979001, 6.73e-05, 0.143216374, 0.000402185, 
5.99e-06, 0.008637892, 0.000906473, 0.030147803, 0.000696942, 
0.06038404, 0.000625457, 0.035261238, 0.042930657, 0.01282187, 
0.030221599, 0.000118513, 0.003552078, 0.002547753, 0.005850736, 
0.0001176, 0.001012019, 0.022458292, 0.023196107, 0.061736236, 
0.010543594, 0.032114583, 1.02e-05, 0.013650841, 0.000419571, 
0.000358173, 0.003873999, 0.000165441, 0.027002225, 0.026133375, 
0.028335404, 0.027503738, 0.000136987, 0.001289475, 0.048530267, 
0.000208896, 0.002173612, 0.023953018, 2.3e-05, 0.019027806, 
0.000495739, 0.011051853, 0.021856285, 0.006643201, 0.011511987, 
1.1e-05, 0.002010242, 0.003117657, 0.117475573, 0.024946637, 
0.058560863, 0.102647711, 0.000379362, 0.000603669, 1.97e-05, 
0.020976103, 0.01459725, 0.000289262, 0.003064517, 0.008196972, 
0.000302017, 0.020562333, 0.093245647, 0.008974985, 0.015369811, 
0.013341021, 0.000146334, 0.045070436, 0.002364084, 0.001069053, 
0.000525468, 0.024699631, 0.000210154, 0.013661305, 0.014193045, 
9.36e-05, 0.008298908, 0.001575832, 0.002778748, 0.026456846, 
0.05169889, 0.023670177, 0.000370742, 0.211737239, 0.011322947, 
0.022878397, 1.95e-06, 0.055530173, 2.34e-05, 8.81e-06, 0.000189184, 
0.000270935, 7.4e-05, 0.000178542, 0.000530574, 0.005837658, 
0.024640248, 0.006536165, 0.011476716, 0.003567421, 0.000424627, 
0.000295164, 6.09e-05, 1.02e-05, 0.043852798, 0.033416026, 0.011645167, 
0.000166027, 6.94e-05, 0.042856405, 0.000429471, 0.00051019, 
0.000530227, 0.006190825, 1.75e-05, 0.023080027, 4.07e-05, 0.001322897, 
0.041780286, 0.000358371, 6.89e-05, 3.47e-05, 0.00132758, 0.001339749, 
0.012596551, 0.003345775, 2.54e-05, 0.000660134, 0.031165069, 
0.000149653, 1.09e-05, 0.009427228, 6.33e-05, 0.030851467, 0.009840297, 
0.008769023, 0.006244515, 6.09e-05, 0.001459698, 0.010502741, 
0.00054124, 0.000238582, 0.000303381, 0.019191567, 5.91e-05), class = "dist", Labels = c("Abruzzo07", 
"Abruzzo14", "Andalucia07", "Andalucia14", "Aquitanie07", "Aquitanie14", 
"Aragon07", "Aragon14", "Asturias07", "Asturias14", "Austria07", 
"Austria14", "Auvergne07", "Auvergne14", "Baden-Wu07", "Baden-Wu14", 
"Baleares07", "Baleares14", "Basilicata07", "Basilicata14", "Basse Normandie07", 
"Basse Normandie14", "Bavaria07", "Bavaria14", "Berlin07", "Berlin14", 
"Bolzano07", "Bolzano14", "Bourgogne07", "Bourgogne14", "Bradenburgh07", 
"Bradenburgh14", "Bremen07", "Bremen14", "Bretagne07", "Bretagne14", 
"Burgenland07", "Burgenland14", "Campania07", "Campania14", "Canarias07", 
"Canarias14", "Cantabria07", "Cantabria14", "Carinthia07", "Carinthia14", 
"CastillaLaMancha07", "CastillaLaMancha14", "CastillayLeon07", 
"CastillayLeon14", "Catalonia07", "Catalonia14", "Centre07", 
"Centre14", "Champagne-Ardenne07", "Champagne-Ardenne14", "Corsica07", 
"Corsica14", "EastWales07", "EastWales14", "Emilia Romagna07", 
"Emilia Romagna14", "England07", "England14", "Franche-Comte07", 
"Franche-Comte14", "Friuli Venezia Giulia07", "Friuli Venezia Giulia14", 
"Hamburg07", "Hamburg14", "Haute Normandie07", "Haute Normandie14", 
"Hessen07", "Hessen14", "Italy07", "Italy14", "La Rioja07", "Lazio07", 
"Lazio14", "Liguria07", "Liguria14", "Limousine07", "Limousine14", 
"Loire07", "Loire14", "Lombardy07", "Lombardy14", "Lorraine07", 
"Lorraine14", "Lower Austria07", "Lower Austria14", "Lower Saxony07", 
"Lower Saxony14", "Madrid07", "Madrid14", "Malta07", "Malta14", 
"Marche07", "Marche14", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern07", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern14", 
"Midi-Pyrenees07", "Midi-Pyrenees14", "Molise07", "Molise14", 
"Murcia07", "Murcia14", "Calais07", "Calais14", "NorthernIreland07", 
"NorthernIreland14", "Picardie07", "Picardie14", "Piemonte07", 
"Piemonte14", "Poitou-Charentes07", "Poitou-Charentes14", "Puglia07", 
"Puglia14", "Rheinland07", "Rheinland14", "Rhone-Alpes07", "Rhone-Alpes14", 
"Saarland07", "Saarland14", "Salzburg07", "Salzburg14", "Sardinia07", 
"Sardinia14", "Saxony-Anhalt07", "Saxony-Anhalt14", "Saxony07", 
"Saxony14", "Schleswig-Holstein07", "Schleswig-Holstein14", "Scotland07", 
"Scotland14", "Sicily07", "Sicily14", "Steiermark07", "Steiermark14", 
"Thuringia07", "Thuringia14", "Trento07", "Trento14", "Tuscany07", 
"Tuscany14", "Tyrol07", "Tyrol14", "Umbria07", "Umbria14", "Upper Austria07", 
"Upper Austria14", "Valencia07", "Valencia14", "Valle d'Aosta07", 
"Valle d'Aosta14", "Veneto07", "Veneto14", "Vienna07", "Vienna14", 
"Vorarlberg014", "Vorarlberg07", "West Wales07", "West Wales14"
), Size = 165, Diag = FALSE, Upper = FALSE)
```

This is the second data.frame

```
MyMeta<- structure(list(Group = structure(c(4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Austria", 
"France", "Germany", "Italy", "Malta", "Spain", "UK"), class = "factor"), 
Group0 = c(4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 
6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 4, 4, 7, 7, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 6, 6, 
5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 7, 7, 
2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 4, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 
4, 4, 1, 1, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7)), .Names = c("Group", 
"Group0"), row.names = c("Abruzzo07", "Abruzzo14", "Andalucia07", 
"Andalucia14", "Aquitanie07", "Aquitanie14", "Aragon07", "Aragon14", 
"Asturias07", "Asturias14", "Austria07", "Austria14", "Auvergne07", 
"Auvergne14", "Baden-Wu07", "Baden-Wu14", "Baleares07", "Baleares14", 
"Basilicata07", "Basilicata14", "Basse Normandie07", "Basse Normandie14", 
"Bavaria07", "Bavaria14", "Berlin07", "Berlin14", "Bolzano07", 
"Bolzano14", "Bourgogne07", "Bourgogne14", "Bradenburgh07", "Bradenburgh14", 
"Bremen07", "Bremen14", "Bretagne07", "Bretagne14", "Burgenland07", 
"Burgenland14", "Campania07", "Campania14", "Canarias07", "Canarias14", 
"Cantabria07", "Cantabria14", "Carinthia07", "Carinthia14", "CastillaLaMancha07", 
"CastillaLaMancha14", "CastillayLeon07", "CastillayLeon14", "Catalonia07", 
"Catalonia14", "Centre07", "Centre14", "Champagne-Ardenne07", 
"Champagne-Ardenne14", "Corsica07", "Corsica14", "EastWales07", 
"EastWales14", "Emilia Romagna07", "Emilia Romagna14", "England07", 
"England14", "Franche-Comte07", "Franche-Comte14", "Friuli Venezia Giulia07", 
"Friuli Venezia Giulia14", "Hamburg07", "Hamburg14", "Haute Normandie07", 
"Haute Normandie14", "Hessen07", "Hessen14", "Italy07", "Italy14","La Rioja07", "Lazio07", "Lazio14", "Liguria07", "Liguria14", 
"Limousine07", "Limousine14", "Loire07", "Loire14", "Lombardy07", 
"Lombardy14", "Lorraine07", "Lorraine14", "Lower Austria07", 
"Lower Austria14", "Lower Saxony07", "Lower Saxony14", "Madrid07", 
"Madrid14", "Malta07", "Malta14", "Marche07", "Marche14", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern07", 
"Mecklenburg-Vorpommern14", "Midi-Pyrenees07", "Midi-Pyrenees14", 
"Molise07", "Molise14", "Murcia07", "Murcia14", "Calais07", "Calais14", 
"NorthernIreland07", "NorthernIreland14", "Picardie07", "Picardie14", 
"Piemonte07", "Piemonte14", "Poitou-Charentes07", "Poitou-Charentes14", 
"Puglia07", "Puglia14", "Rheinland07", "Rheinland14", "Rhone-Alpes07", 
"Rhone-Alpes14", "Saarland07", "Saarland14", "Salzburg07", "Salzburg14", 
"Sardinia07", "Sardinia14", "Saxony-Anhalt07", "Saxony-Anhalt14", 
"Saxony07", "Saxony14", "Schleswig-Holstein07", "Schleswig-Holstein14", 
"Scotland07", "Scotland14", "Sicily07", "Sicily14", "Steiermark07", 
"Steiermark14", "Thuringia07", "Thuringia14", "Trento07", "Trento14", 
"Tuscany07", "Tuscany14", "Tyrol07", "Tyrol14", "Umbria07", "Umbria14", 
"Upper Austria07", "Upper Austria14", "Valencia07", "Valencia14", 
"Valle d'Aosta07", "Valle d'Aosta14", "Veneto07", "Veneto14", 
"Vienna07", "Vienna14", "Vorarlberg014", "Vorarlberg07", "West Wales07", 
"West Wales14"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `legend` code, `levels(MyMeta$Group)` means `[1] "Austria" "France"  "Germany" "Italy"   "Malta"   "Spain"   "UK"`. But `MyMeta$Group0` means `[1] 4 4 6 6 2 2 6 6 6 6 1 2 2 3 ...`. `pch` and `col` aren't assinged to `legend`. I presented some of methods of solving it.

```
## the most easy method (if your Group0 isn't alphabetical order, this method can't be used.)
legend(x="bottomleft", legend=levels(MyMeta$Group), col=1:7, pch=1:7)
                                 #  you can use seq.int(levels(MyMeta$Group)) instead of 1:7

## a versatile method (this method doesn't need the condition of Group0)
legend(x="top", legend=unique(MyMeta$Group), col=unique(MyMeta$Group0), pch=unique(MyMeta$Group0))

  # if you want alphabetical order,
  library(dplyr)
  MyMeta %>% distinct(Group, Group0) %>% arrange(Group) %>% 
    with(legend(x="bottomright", legend=Group, col=Group0, pch=Group0))
```

[image]

#### [ A smarter method @Gavin Simpson gave ]

See the comment for more information.

```
library(vegan)
pco2 <- capscale(vec2 ~ 1, add = TRUE)

pchv <- 1:7
colv <- 1:7

ordiplot(pco2, display = 'sites', type = 'n', cex=.75, main="Biotechnology Dissimilarity")
with(MyMeta, points(pco2, col=colv[Group], pch=pchv[Group]))
with(MyMeta, legend(x="bottomleft", legend=levels(Group), col=colv, pch=pchv))
```

Comment: I find that you are better off setting up a vector of the unique colours, plotting characters that you want, and then index that vector by the factor, eg: `pch = pchs[myfactor]` where `pchs` might be the values `c(1,2,19,21)` and `myfactor` is a factor with 4 levels. I've blogged about this [here.](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2012/04/11/customising-vegans-ordination-plots/), which you might be interested in.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson; Thank you for your advice. I added the method you taught to the Answer (Are you ok ?)